# Presente e imperfecto del subjuntivo en las subordinaciones adjetivas

Tags: subjuntivo

1. Si pudieras vivir donde **quieras/quieres**, donde vivirías?
2. Si yo tuviera la casa que **está/esté** en Madrid, viviría allí.
3. Si me hubieran regalado la casa que **estuviera/estuvo** en Madrid, viviría allí.

¿Cómo es correcto usar subjuntivo o indicativo en las subordinaciones adjetivas? Hay unas reglas?

Comment: Pienso que como regla general el verbo que es en subjuntivo sigue la misma forma que el primer verbo. Pudieras -> quieras. Tuviera -> está. Hubieran -> estuviera. Sobre las reglas no las conozco, pues se trata de casos muy específicos en mi opinión. Veamos qué dicen los otros.

Comment: It is not quite clear the meaning of sentences 2 and 3. Could you write them in English to know it exactly?

Comment: It may just be a matter of a poorly chosen example but sentences #2 and especially #3 give the impression that the house can move. I would vote for _está_ in sentence #2 and none of the above for sentence #3, where I'd say _"...la casa *que estaba* en Madrid"_, or better _"...la casa *que hay* en Madrid"_ or, eveb better yet _"la casa *de* Madrid"_ for both sentences, but then the verb tense concordance example is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that by the second and third sentences you want to say:

1. If I had the house that's in Madrid, I would live there.
2. If they had given me the house that was in Madrid, I would have lived there.

Because you have a definite article I would say to use the indicative.

1. "Si yo tuviera la casa que está en Madrid, viviría allÍ" (mejor: la casa en Madrid)
2. "Si me hubieran regalado la casa que estaba en Madrid, habría vivido allí"

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted to say. It is very clear in English but Spanish subjunctive always makes me sad.

Comment: @AndreySmirnov if the answer was helpfull please vote the answer up. If it was the best answer and solve your doubts please select the tick.

Answer (score 4):

I think that *estar* is a tricky verb for the example as I've said in the comments.

I agree with fedorqui on sentence #1

> Si **pudieras** vivir donde **quisieras**, ¿Dónde vivirías?

In sentences #2 and #3 your problem is that you are looking for concordance in the subordinate sentence (the one introduced by *que*), and while you certainly cannot use any tense, there is no requirement for concordance.

Let's rephrase sentence #2 without *estar*, which IMHO shows it more clearly:

> Si **vendieran** el coche, lo **compraría**.

The concordance is *vendieran* (imperfect subjunctive)/*compraría*(conditional indicative).

But in this sentence:

> Si **vendieran** el coche que **vi** en Madrid, lo **compraría**.

But you can replace *vi* for a number of tenses: *he visto*, *había visto*, *veo*, *veré*... They all work, although they convey a slightly different meaning. Similarly you can replace the subordinate sentence by other complements:

> Si **vendieran** el coche de Madrid, lo **compraría**.
>
> Si **vendieran** el coche amarillo, lo **compraría**.

Can't resist to mention the name of the song by *Les Luthiers*:

> [Quien **conociera** a María, **amaría** a María](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1tzdgEr83AQ).

The same could be said about sentence #3

Comment: +1 because mentioning Les Luthiers is always a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

1. Si pudieras vivir donde **quisieras**, ¿donde lo harías?

Regarding the other sentences, it is not clear what you want to say.

1. Si yo tuviera la casa que **está/esté** en Madrid, viviría allí.
2. Si me hubieran regalado la casa que **estuviera/estuvo** en Madrid, viviría allí.

For reference, you can check the [Segundo condicional](http://www.denverspanishhouse.com/lesson-plans/condicional-y-segunda-condicional-si-tuviera-m%C3%A1s-tiempo-estudiar%C3%AD-espa%C3%B1ol).